# Como funciona uma sessão no express?

Tags: node.js, session, express.js

Estou com um problema ao fazer login em minha aplicação. Se um usuário faz o login, ele fica logado pra todos que acessam o site. Poderiam me explicar como funciona uma sessão para eu entender melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, quando o usuário faz login em sua aplicação é salvo um cookie no client side para identificar que este usuário esta logado.
Enquanto o cookie for válido a aplicação entende que o usuário esta logado, assim que o cookie expira a aplicação deve requisitar para que o mesmo faça o login novamente.

A propriedade `maxAge`do cookie é quem informa quando aquele cookie deve expirar, por padrão ela não tem nenhum valor, mas você pode adicionar esse tempo em milissegundos, assim quando o cookie for criado ele vai pegar a hora do servidor e adicionar os milissegundos que você informou para gerar a informação de quando aquele cookie deve ser expirado.

Caso ache necessário pode dar uma lida na [documentação](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html).

Comment: Show, esclareceu bastante. Mais uma pergunta, tem como eu armazenar dados em uma sessão?

Comment: @XTRADEXTRADE tem sim, para acessar use a propriedade da sessão `req.session

`, da uma olhada na documentação que lhe passei que tem um exemplo de como utilizar  está propriedade! Obs: caso a resposta tenha resolvido sua dúvida, por favor considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com está mesma dúvida!

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado!